# Unit test for window.location.href within an AJAX request using mocha/chai

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, teaspoon

I need to test whether or not `window.location.href = data.redirect_path` ever happens. How would I mock this in Sinon without it redirecting me away from my test runner? I'm using chai/mocha.js with teaspoon as my test runner.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: $url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { user: $userData },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success == true) {
        window.location.href = data.redirect_path
      } else {
        $errorsContainer.html(data.html);
        $codeInput.select();
        if (typeof data.redirect_path !== 'undefined') {
          window.location.href = data.redirect_path
        }              
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been pulling my hair out for the last 2-3 hours over a similar issue. Unfortunately, navigating away by using the `window.location = href` was a very important behaviour in my plugin so I couldn't just take it on faith. Above using `window.location.assign(href)` did not work for me - maybe due to `jsdom`, not sure.

Finally I've came up with a (fairly) simple solution that works in my case.

```
it('reloads the page when using the browsers back button', (done) => {
    let stub = sinon.stub(window, 'location').set(() => { done() });

    // do whatever you need to here to trigger
    // window.location = href in your application
});
```

I know that it operates on the long timeout, so when it fails you've got to wait for it but that's a much better trade-off for me than having no tests proving my plugin behaves as expected.

> NOTE `jsdom` does *not* have a setter for `window.location` originally but `sinon` lets you create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can `stub` on the `$` for `ajax` as shown below. This needs some refactoring on your code so that it is easily testable.

Your success callback needs to be like this,

```
success: function(data) {
      if (data.success == true) {
        window.location.assign(data.redirect_path)
      } else {
        $errorsContainer.html(data.html);
        $codeInput.select();
        if (typeof data.redirect_path !== 'undefined') {
          window.location.assign(data.redirect_path);
        }              
      }
    }
```

Refer the [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp) how `location.assign` is working.

```
it("should fake successful ajax request", function () {
    sinon.stub($, "ajax").yieldsTo("success", {redirect_path: '/home', success: true});
    sinon.stub(window.location, 'assign'); // stubbing the assign. so that it wont redirect to the given url.

    //here you call the function which invokes $.ajax();
     someFunction();

    // assert here 

     // manually restoring the stubs.
     $.ajax.restore();
     window.location.assign.restore();
})
```